# Content editor issue with Times New Roman fonts

Tags: html

I have an issue with Content Editor - for my template I need to use Times New Roman font, but when I add it to table tag style property it rips off everything and returns table tag like this:

> table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" normal;"="" font-weight:="" #9b7d31;="" color:="" 18px;="" font-size:="" roman",times,serif;="" new="" times="" style=""

I add font family in single quotes. Any ideas why this happening?

Comment: It is something wrong with your code, is it real? :)))

Comment: My style properties: `style="font-family:'Times New Roman', Times, serif; font-size:26px; color:#9b7d31; font-weight:normal; border-top:4px solid #000001;"`